# subfigure placement incorrect with 4 figures

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I am having an issue with latex placing my figures incorrectly. I have 4 related plots that I want to appear together as a single figure (with a,b,c,d sub-references).

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfigure[All instances]{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/all_Q_time}
\label{fig:q_time_all}
}
\subfigure[SAT instances]{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/all_sat_Q_time}
\label{fig:q_time_sat}
}
\subfigure[UNSAT instances]{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/all_unsat_Q_time}
\label{fig:q_time_unsat}
}
\subfigure[Uniform Random Sample]{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/sample_Q_time}
\label{fig:q_time_sample}
}
\caption{Q metric plotted against time}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

This should display an even 4*4 grid of plots, each the same size. However what happens is that the top right plot is offset on the x-axis, such that the left hand side of it is in the middle of the space (i.e. roughly offset by 50% of its width)[image]

Any suggestion of how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `center` around `figure`, but rather `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`. You seem to be using the obsolete package `subfigure`. Please, make the example selfcontained, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, with the packages necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks very much. I did try using a different package (cant remember the name) but it seemed a lot more complicated, and I couldn't make it work at all. This was an odd bug because when figure size was set to 0.5 it worked fine

Comment: Spaces between "words" of a paragraph line are stretched equally, *except* the last line of the paragraph, which has all the stretch pushed to the end. Do the following: put the `center` environment inside the figure environment (but better to use `\centering` instead) and end the first line with a double backslash (after the second figure. If the figures end up too close together, add appropriate space commands between them (I would use `\hfil`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centering should be declared *after* `\begin{figure}`. Use

```
\begin{figure}[htp] % not h only
\centering
\subfigure[All instances]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/all_Q_time}%
\label{fig:q_time_all}%
}\hfil
\subfigure[SAT instances]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/all_sat_Q_time}%
\label{fig:q_time_sat}%
}

\subfigure[UNSAT instances]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/all_unsat_Q_time}%
\label{fig:q_time_unsat}%
}\hfil
\subfigure[Uniform Random Sample]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{timeregression/graphs/bucketing/sample_Q_time}%
\label{fig:q_time_sample}%
}

\caption{Q metric plotted against time}
\end{figure}
```

However, `\subfigure` is a command from the obsolete package `subfigure`. Load `subfig`, instead, and change `\subfigure` into `\subfloat`.

Note also the `%` in various places, to avoid spurious spaces creeping in. I split into two parts the subfloat inclusions and added `\hfil` between the two on the same line, so the spacing will be equally divided between left, center and right.

You can also consider the more recent and very powerful `subcaption` package (that requires a different syntax, though).