# Creating figure with multiple images

Tags: spacing

how to create a figure of ( 4 x 4 ) images ? how can I manage the spaces between raws and colomns?

Comment: Will they require a subcaption?

Comment: We have many of this type of question on this site. While not an exact duplicate, you can follow the discussion in [subfigure placement incorrect with 4 figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156893/5764) to get an idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of packages which could be used here if the subfigures require subcaptions; [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) or [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) could be used; please, refer to the documentation of the packages to see all the features they offer.

Here's a little example using `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testa}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testb}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testc}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testd}
\end{subfigure}\par\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:teste}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testg}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testh}
\end{subfigure}\par\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testi}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testj}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testk}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testl}
\end{subfigure}\par\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testm}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testn}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testo}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.25\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{sfig:testp}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Sixteen subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If no subcaptioning is required, apply the same idea and substitute everywhere in my code `subfigure` by `minipage` and delete the inner `\caption` and `\label` commands.